# Two y tick placements on middle y axis

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the MWE below. The blue line runs on top of  `-1`. Can we move the y ticks to the RH side on `y<0`? How?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3.3,xmax=3.3,
    ymin=-1.4,ymax=1.4,
    axis x line=middle,    
    axis y line=middle, 
    ytick={-1,0,1},
    ]
     \addplot[thick,blue,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:0,samples=2] {-1};
    \addplot[thick,red,domain=0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},samples=2] {1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `extra y tick` for -1, and change the `ticklabel style` of that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3.3,xmax=3.3,
    ymin=-1.4,ymax=1.4,
    axis x line=middle,    
    axis y line=middle, 
    ytick={0,1},
    extra y ticks={-1},
    extra y tick style={tick label style={right=3pt}}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,blue,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:0,samples=2] {-1};
    \addplot[thick,red,domain=0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},samples=2] {1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Another possibility

Warning: ugly hack follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3.3,xmax=3.3,
    ymin=-1.4,ymax=1.4,
    axis x line=middle,    
    axis y line=middle, 
    ytick={-1,0,1},
    yticklabel={%
      \ifdim\tick pt <0pt
        \rlap{\quad\axisdefaultticklabel}
      \else
         \axisdefaultticklabel
      \fi
    }
    ]
    \addplot[thick,blue,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:0,samples=2] {-1};
    \addplot[thick,red,domain=0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},samples=2] {1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case we could and will. But it would be nice to know if we can do this generally

Comment: @daleif I don't know of any elegant ways of doing it, but see above for a not-so-elegant one.